# How can I color the dynamic data of the pie chart using morris js?

Tags: php, mysql, charts, morris.js

I fetched the data from the database and with the help of Morris JS I showed it on Donut pie chart. But the color of the pie chart sections seems similar . How can I change the color of the different section in pie chart.

Here is the Code :

```
$row->execute(); 
$json_data=array();  
foreach($row as $rec)  
{  
$json_array['label']=$rec['user_type'];  
$json_array['value']=$rec['id']; 

array_push($json_data,$json_array);  
}  

{ ?>    
<div id="donut-example" style="height: 250px;"></div>

<script type="application/javascript">

Morris.Donut({
element: 'donut-example',
data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data)?>
});

</script>
```

And here is the result Image :
[image: pie chart by morris]

please tell me how can I change the color in different section of the Pie Chart.

Comment: I think that link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588213/how-to-change-label-color-in-donut-morris-chart-customized-label-colors

Comment: @Bizzu I believe you have misunderstood the question, the `labelColor` is not the same as the actual color of the curved lines which make up the donut and the OP is asking how to change those lines, as such, this isn't a duplicate of the question you have linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Morris Donut [example](https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/blob/master/examples/donut-colors.html), you need to provide an array of colours:

```
Morris.Donut({
 colors: [
    '#0BA462',
    '#39B580',
    '#67C69D',
    '#95D7BB'
  ]
});
```

There is the ability also to set the `labelColor` globally or individually (per datum).

Comment: can you please tell me where should I wrie this code in my file ?

Comment: @AbnitChauhan As my example shows, you need to add the property `colors` to the object you are passing to `Morris.Donut`.

Comment: <script type="application/javascript">

Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut-example',
  data: <?php echo json_encode($json_data)?>
  });

Morris.Donut({
 colors: [
    '#0BA462',
    '#39B580',
    '#67C69D',
    '#95D7BB'
  ]
});

</script>

Comment: I added the code in the script above . still it doesn't change anything. please help.

Comment: Please reread my comment, you can't just copy & paste my example and expect it to work, as my answer says, you need to provide and array of colours and my comment states you need to pass it to the existing call of `Morris.Donut`. Does that make more sense?